# python- Evaluating large floating point number against its rounded equivilent

Tags: python

I have a a file like this,

...

3.999999000000e-003   1.2344325e-003

4.000000000000e-003   1.2342323e-003

...

I am trying to find find only values equal to 0.004 (4.000000000000e-003 long form) but I dont want to have to input the long form as the precisions can change from file to file. I have to do a line split beforehand, so I also have to convert it from a string first.

How can I evaluate something like 0.004 == 4.000000000000e-003 in python?

I currently have been trying stuff like, but obviously its not working

```
        line_tmp = line.split()

        if float(line_tmp[0]) == 0.004:
            print(line_tmp[0])
            print(float(line_tmp[0]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to compare two floating point numbers, you should check whether the difference between them is incredibly small. Something like:

```
if abs(number1 - number2) < 1e-8:
    # Do something
```

Comment: Thanks seems to work nicely. It seems like there would be a more elegant solution tho.